# LTSpice to EAGLE: Can't create directory

Tags: ltspice, eaglecad

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I want to import my schematic from LTspice in EAGLE, but when I try to import it this error pops up:

[image]

Comment: Windows prevents "ordinary" programs from writing in the Program Files or Program Files(86) directories.  I would make a working directory under "Documents" to store my working files.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using LTspice IV instead of LTspice XVII?  You're not using Windows XP, so I can't see an obvious reason.  LTspice XVII installs a shadow copy of all its library files in `Documents\LTspiceXVII` so it would make your problem easier to deal with since this shadow copy is meant to be where you add/modify things.